# position: fixed

Tags: html, css

Можно ли через position: fixed закрепить блок только при вертикальной прокрутке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значение fixed - оно и в Африке fixed, т.е. нет понятия "зафиксировать только по горизонтали или вертикали". Стандартные средства CSS это не предусматривают, а вот с помощью JS, теоретически, это сделать можно.

Comment: То есть только js, чистым CSS никак? Ну и хрен с ним тогда)

Comment: @Dazar, Чего вы так? )) Сейчас практически не осталось сайтов, которые не используют JS. Решение, на самом деле, очень простое. Вот и [примерчик вам](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/5eXGv/).

Comment: Спасибо, я и сам представляю, как это делается, просто я это спрашивал для проэкта типа "ой, Денис(эт я), мне сказали ты сайты умеешь делать? А не поможешь мне мой в человеческий вид привести?", так что лень заморачиваться)

Answer (score 0):

Используй `position:sticky`, оно реагирует на скролинг по горизонтали и фиксируется при скроле по вертикали.